# Protecting files in folder on server

Tags: php, security, permissions

I am working on a website where im goign to be storing pictures of customers Drivers Licences and proof of insurances on my server. 
I don't want the information to get into the wrong hands or out on the internet (ie google images ect)
Im trying to come up with the best practice for storing these images.

If i set my folder for these images to 7,0,0 permissions will this be good enough? Or is there something more i can do to secure these fiels?

Do i need to move the directory out side the public_html folder? do i do both? other options?

These files will be uploaded to the directory via php/html form.

I will **NEVER** need the public to see the content of this folder.

Right now im in development and just have test images in there and im using 
 in a index.html in that folder and set permissions to 6,4,0 and the files to 6,4,0 .

Comment: "Do i need to move the directory out side the public_html folder" - Yes, publishing private data on the internet is probably something to avoid :)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't store your images inside the public_html folder.

The best practice would be creating a folder before the public_html folder, and store the images there. As you are not even planning to display the pictures, why should you store them inside the `public_html` folder.

Saving the images in a upper folder than `public_html` isn't a problem and can be achieved with PHP.

I got following folder structure:

```
- uploaded_images
- www
   -- index.php
```

You can not access uploaded_images with a link, and if I need to show images, I load them via PHP.